# Diferença de meses entre duas datas, sem considerar o dia do mês

Tags: java, datetime, data

Estou fazendo uma aplicação para cálculos trabalhistas. Preciso receber duas datas e saber a quantidade de dias/ meses/ anos.

Ex.: de 08/03/2017 à 07/03/2018 é para dar 12 meses exatos, no meu código dá 11 meses e 27 dias. Alguém sabe como consertar isso?

```
String dataEntrada, dataSaida;
dataEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite a data de entrada");
dataSaida = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite a data de saida");
String entrada[] = dataEntrada.split("/");
String saida[] = dataSaida.split("/");

LocalDate admissao = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(entrada[2]), Integer.parseInt(entrada[1]),
        Integer.parseInt(entrada[0]));
LocalDate demissao = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(saida[2]), Integer.parseInt(saida[1]),
        Integer.parseInt(saida[0]));
Period periodo = Period.between(admissao, demissao);
System.out
        .println(periodo.getYears() + " Anos " + periodo.getMonths() + " Meses " + periodo.getDays() + " Dias");
```

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que [`Period.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-), de certa forma, "arredonda para baixo". Para que um mês exato seja considerado, o dia do mês deve ser maior ou igual ao do início.

Por exemplo, se começar em 08/03/2017 e terminar em 07/04/2017:

```
LocalDate admissao = LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 8);
LocalDate demissao = LocalDate.of(2017, 4, 7);
Period periodo = Period.between(admissao, demissao);
System.out.println(periodo.getYears() + " Anos " + periodo.getMonths() + " Meses " + periodo.getDays() + " Dias");
```

A saída será:

> 0 Anos **0** Meses 30 Dias

Como eu comecei no dia 8 de março, a API só considera um mês inteiro a partir de 8 de abril. Portanto se eu mudar as datas para:

```
LocalDate admissao = LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 8);
LocalDate demissao = LocalDate.of(2017, 4, 8);
```

A saída será:

> 0 Anos **1** Meses 0 Dias

No seu exemplo, o período começa em 08/03/2017 e termina em 07/03/2018, portanto o décimo segundo mês não foi completado (só seria completado a partir de 08/03/2018).

Esta é a forma que a API faz os cálculos e não há como mudar. Se sua regra para considerar um mês inteiro é diferente, algumas adaptações devem ser feitas.

Uma solução seria somar um dia na data de demissão (conforme sugerido na [resposta do @prmottajr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281394/112052)), e depois subtrair este dia a mais de `periodo.getDays()`.

Não sei exatamente qual a sua regra. É a partir do dia 07/03/2018 que você considera 12 meses? Ou a partir de 01/03/2018 já deve retornar 12 meses?

Se for o segundo caso (a partir de 01/03/2018 já considera 12 meses), você pode simplesmente ignorar o dia (transformando o `LocalDate` em um [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html), usando o método [`from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-)) e calcular a quantidade de meses entre eles, usando um [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html):

```
// YearMonth.from extrai o mês e o ano do LocalDate
YearMonth mesAnoAdmissao = YearMonth.from(admissao);
YearMonth mesAnoDemissao = YearMonth.from(demissao);
// quantidade de meses entre admissão e demissão
long meses = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(mesAnoAdmissao, mesAnoDemissao);
```

No caso, como estou usando `YearMonth` e esta classe só possui mês e ano (sem nenhuma informação sobre o dia), o resultado será a diferença em meses, sem levar em conta o dia do mês (e portanto, sem os "problemas" citados acima).

Com isso, `meses` será igual a 12. Depois você pode ajustar para a quantidade de anos, caso `meses` seja maior que 12, por exemplo:

```
long anos = meses / 12;
meses = meses - (anos * 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

O método between ***não*** inclui a data final. Experimente fazer:

```
LocalDate demissao = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(saida[2]), Integer.parseInt(saida[1]),
                Integer.parseInt(saida[0])+1);
```

Comment: Da certo, porém na contagem de dias conta como um dia a mais.